# Get validation to work with Maven and Requestfactory on Eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, validation, gwt, requestfactory

I have a project setup with Maven and using RequestFactory. However I cannot get the validation to work through maven settings. This is how my maven setup looks like:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${target.jdk}</source>
            <target>${target.jdk}</target>
            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            <proc>none</proc>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
                <artifactId>requestfactory-apt</artifactId>
                <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

I have also added Hibernate validator.

On the Eclipse side, I have tried various things, among which the most correct one looks like this:

[image]

I also have installed the m2e-apt plugin.

However I still can't get the validation tool to run. I don't get validation errors if I make mistakes on purpose and of course, when I run my application I get the infamous

> SEVERE: Unexpected error
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for the ...

Anyone has any idea of what I am missing? Should I simply resign myself to configure Eclipse manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly disabled annotation processing in the `maven-compiler-plugin`'s configuration:

```
<proc>none</proc>
```

Remove that line and it should run annotation processors.

Note that [there's a regression](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-202) with `maven-compiler-plugin` 3.x where the plugin dependencies no longer are taken into account when compiling (it probably never was thought as a *feature*) so your `requestfactory-apt` would not be seen by JavaC with recent `maven-compiler-plugin` versions and you'd still have the same problem then.

The only way to reliably use annotation processors with Maven is to declare them as project dependencies with either `<scope>provided</scope>` or `<optional>true</optional>`, or to use the `maven-processor-plugin`. There's an open feature request for better support in Maven proper through the `maven-compiler-plugin`: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-203

Comment: I am using `maven-compiler-plugin` 2.5.1 so I am not affected by the regression. But I still moved the `requestfactory-apt` dependency to the project dependencies and it works just fine. This way I am covered for the future